# Select two different id record with most recent datetime?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question regarding a SQl query in mysql .I want to  select  two rows with the most recent datetime where id = 1 or id = 3

Table Records

```
 id   |  datetime                |          count
 -------------------------------------------------------
 1    |  2018-01-02 11:00:00     |           1
 2    |  2018-01-02 11:00:00     |           0
 3    |  2018-01-02 11:00:00     |           1
 1    |  2018-01-02 10:55:00     |           0
 2    |  2018-01-02 10:55:00     |           0
 3    |  2018-01-02 10:55:00     |           0
 1    |  2018-01-02 10:50:00     |           1
 2    |  2018-01-02 10:50:00     |           1
 3    |  2018-01-02 10:50:00     |           1
```

I am expecting my query to rerturn the most recent transaction which should be :

```
     id    |  datetime                |          count
 -------------------------------------------------------
      1    |  2018-01-02 11:00:00     |           1
      3    |  2018-01-02 11:00:00     |           1
```

Can someone please give me any suggestions?

Comment: What queries have you tried prior to asking this question?

Comment: If you're still struggling see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id,
       max(datetime),
       count 
from t1 where id in (1,3)
group by id
```

**t1 is your table

Answer (score 0):

Try a union

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1) t1
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE id = 3 ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1) t2;
```

Answer (score -1):

`select * from tablename where id in (1, 3) order by datetime desc limit 2`

Comment: I want to get id = 1 and id = 3  records

Comment: MySQL does not support the `TOP` operator.

Answer (score -1):

Do an inner join with a subquery that returns the most recent transactions for ID 1 and 3:

```
Select only
     , the
     , columns
     , you
     , actually 
     , want
FROM myTable tbl
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT 
 id, 
 MAX(datetime) AS most_recent_tran
 FROM myTable
 WHERE ID in (1,3)
 GROUP BY id
) temp

ON

WHATEVER I JUST CALLED MY COLUMNS

 tbl.ID = temp.ID and tbl.datetime = temp.datetime
```